# Having difficulties to login in JetBrains account

Tags: proxy, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I am using PyCharm and WebStorm professional edition and I have 1 year free student subscription. But I cant login to my JetBrains account with any of my browser to activate or register directly from PyCharm/WebStorm.

Whenever I try to login from PyCharm/WebStorm this comes up:

> JetBrains account connection error:connection refused:connect

or sometimes it wants the information on proxy host and proxy server. It only occurs on my specific device.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 9):

Please check your system `hosts` file. If there's anything related to `account.jetbrains.com` there, remove that line.

Comment: thank you.It worked. It was 0.0.0.0 for JetBrains .com. I don't know  how that happened